# What is equivalent of id<type> in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have two delegates like this:

```
protocol MyFirstDelegate {
  func change(value: int) 
}

protocol MySecondDelegate {
  weak var delegate: MyFirstDelegate?
}
```

Those protocols are implemented in two customized UIViewControllers:

```
class MyFirstViewController: UIViewController, MyFirstDelegate {
  ...
}

class MySecondViewController: UIViewController, MySecondDelegate {
  ...
}
```

The first UI view controller will push second UI view controller by using a segue.

In my first UI view controller class I have the following codes to prepare segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
  if let vc = (segue.destinationViewController) as? MySecondViewController {
    vc.delegate = self
  }
}
```

The above codes compile without any problem. However, I think that the first UI controller has knowledge about the next view controller class. I prefer to pass delegate like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
  if var vc = (segue.destinationViewController) as? MySecondDelegate {
    vc.delegate = self
  }
}
```

I got compiling error:

```
Cannot assign to property: "vc" is immutable.
```

It seems that as to a concrete UI view controller is OK, but not to a protocol. Any explanation and solution to this?

By the way, in Objective-C, this can be done like this:

```
id<NSObject, MySecondDelegate> vc = segue.destinationViewController;
vc.delegate = self;
```

I could not find a way in swift to define a variable like

```
let vc: AnyObject<type>? // like id<type>
```

**UPDATES**

As @David_Berry solution, it works if I mark protocol as class. The above codes are actually simplified ones. I am in the middle of converting my ObjC codes to Swift. Therefore, I have to mark protocols as objc:

```
@objc protocol MyFirstDelegate : class {
  func change(value: int) 
}

@objc protocol MySecondDelegate {
  weak var delegate: MyFirstDelegate?
}
```

with @objc, I still get the same compiling error.

Comment: Is MySecondDelegate an Obj-C protocol? In Swift you'd need to specify `get` and/or `set`. Your code doesn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to get your example to compile, you have a LOT of inconsistencies.  The key to your actual problem, I think, is requiring that the protocols be class protocols:

```
protocol XXX : class { }
```

Says that only types that are classes can be declared to implement XXX.

But, I'm really not sure that's your problem, there were so many other changes required (you spelled MySecondDelegate at least two ways, MySecondViewController at least two ways, etc.

The compiling example is:

```
// This protocol has to be class so that delegate can be weak
protocol MyFirstDelegate : class {
    func change(value: Int)
}

protocol MySecondDelegate {
    weak var delegate: MyFirstDelegate? { get set }
}

class MyFirstViewController: UIViewController, MyFirstDelegate {
    func change(value: Int) {

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if var vc = (segue.destinationViewController) as? MySecondDelegate {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

class MySecondViewController: UIViewController, MySecondDelegate {
    weak var delegate : MyFirstDelegate?
}
```

As for your question, there is no swift synonym to the objective-C syntax `id<Protocol>` or `Class<Protocol>`  There are multiple duplicates to that issue that offer alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help. I tried to simplify my codes. Actually, I am in the middle of converting my ObjC codes to Swift. During the process, i have to mark my protocols as @objc. As a result, I still get the same compiling error.